# webpack bootstrap sass fonts url

Tags: sass, webpack, webpack-style-loader

I've configured my fonts to be put in a /fonts folder

`{test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf)$/, loader: "file?name=fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash]"}`

and my sass is being converted to css and extracted to the /css folder as per below

```
{test: /\.scss/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style", "css!sass")}
```

and

```
new ExtractTextPlugin("css/styles.css", {
    allChunks: true
})
```

The issue is that when I view via web browser by using browser sync and serving from my /dist folder which has those 2 folders mentioned above inside, the css tries to load fonts by going to /css/fonts. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you add your project folder structure as well for better understanding of the problem.  Also your question is not so clear. Please elaborate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I just had to update my loaders to have a / at the front of my file param e.g.

`{test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf)$/, loader: "file?name=/fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash]"}`

instead of

`{test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf)$/, loader: "file?name=fonts/[name].[ext]?[hash]"}`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I killed hours struggling with this exact same problem